# Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: crystal-reports

We recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 and now need a newer version of CR.

1. The user machines have CR version 13.0.5 (which has 13.0.2000 DLLs).
2. The development machines have CR version 13.0.22 (which has 13.0.3500 DLLs).

I figured deploying 13.0.3500 DLLs would be acceptable because its a newer version, but the user machines seem to report a variety of different errors such as unable to find 13.0.3500 DLLs.  The previously compiled applications don't work with the new version so there's a problem either way.

It seems that an upgrade on a single machine is a breaking change.  The problem seems to be that in order to make a conversion, all the applications and user machines would have to be upgraded simultaneously, which isn't practical.  Is there any way to make a gradual conversion allowing the environment to both on both user/developer machines and use a common config file those with 13.0.5 and 13.0.22?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following configuration to app.config. 
change the oldVersion & newVersion accordingly

```
<runtime> 
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
</dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/> 
</dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/> </dependentAssembly>

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/> </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/> </dependentAssembly> 

<dependentAssembly> 
<assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/> <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/> </dependentAssembly> 

</assemblyBinding> 
</runtime>
/configuration>
```

Source:
[crystal report for visual studio 2017](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2017 for developers and install in development machine. Also you have to install the run-time (either 64-bit or 32-bit) in user machines. Do not forget to uninstall previously any existed old version of Crystal Reports.The link for Crystal Reports is this http://www.crystalreports.com/crvs/confirm/.If you have  web-environment in user machines don't forget to check c:\inetpub\wwwroot if there a Web.Config which must be updated for CR DLL's (13.0.3500).
Good luck!

Comment: its not a web application...i ended up having to create something to handle the appdomain.assemblyresolve event..otherwise i could have had to configure lots of users systems

Comment: Sigh, you still need to download and install the runtime on the target machine, the sigh is one of sympathy I read it's not a web application.